# Prove that the factor ring $R/\ker(\phi)$ is trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra

That's a question I have come across in my review and I am having trouble with proving the trivial part. I am not looking for a full answer, but more of a pointer. I looked through my textbook again and am having trouble coming up with a path to the solution.

Comment: If $a$ is non-zero then $a$ is invertible so $\phi(1)=\phi(a)\phi(a^{-1})=... $ so $\phi(x)=\phi(x)\phi(1)=...$

Comment: $\ker(\phi)$ is a subset of $F$, not $R$, so $R/\ker(\phi)$ doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of $\phi$ is an ideal.  But in a field the only ideals are $0$ and $\Bbb F$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is the structure of $\text{ker}(\phi)$ inside of $F$? As a result, where does the fact $F$ is a field come into play?